# OpenCV: How to get the GMM co-variance matrix?

Tags: opencv

I am using cv::EM to train the GMMs. Everything works fine except when I want to get the co-variance matrix I got a Debug Assertion Failed.

The code is:

```
cout << "Test the EM algorithm in Opencv" << endl;
cv::EM em(5);
em.train(training_set);
cout << "Finished trainging EM" << endl;
if (em.isTrained())
{
    const cv::Mat &weights =  em.get<cv::Mat>("weights");
    const cv::Mat &Means = em.get<cv::Mat>("means");
    const vector<cv::Mat> &Covs = em.get<vector<cv::Mat>>("covs");
}
system("pause");
```

and the error message is:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: D:\Kinect test\GMM\GMM\x64\Debug\GMM.exe File:
>   f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c Line: 1424
>
> Expression: _pFirstBlock == pHead
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure,
>   see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

I am using opencv2.4.13 and visual studio 2015. 
I had read lots of documents, but none of them helps.
Please help me with that. Thank you!

Comment: Why aren't you using `EM::getMeans()`, `EM::getWeights()` and `EM::getCovs()`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Aren't those function for OpenCV3? I am using OpenCV2 and C++.